# VB.net Button_Click event fires multiple times that supposed to fire once

Tags: vb.net

I have 1 button on my windows form in a Desktop based application that appear to fire multiple times. It is supposed to perform one database operation "Insert" when clicked, but it performs the operation multiple times when clicked only once. This only happens occasionally in 2 to 3 months and I've confirmed through debugging that it indeed fires and calls the database function multiple times, in one case 15 times with a single click.
After clicking the button I have also put the code to disable the button and also put a validation check that If the button is enable true then go.

My computer Physical Mouse button is working fine.

Button Code is given below !

```
Private Sub BTnSave_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    Dim CN As New SqlConnection("data source=.;network library=dbmssocn; initial catalog=MyDb; user id=sa; password=abc125;")
    If BtnSave.Enabled = True Then
        Dim inscmd3 As New SqlCommand("insert into Product(id,Name,Category) values(@id,@Name,@Category)")
        With inscmd3
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", lblid.text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtName.text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", txtCategory.text)
        End With
        inscmd3.Connection = CN
        inscmd3.Connection.Open()
        inscmd3.ExecuteNonQuery()
        inscmd3.Connection.Close()
        MsgBox("Item Inserted Successfully")
        btnSave.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You are saying that certain behaviour happens once every 2 or 3 months; and you are assuming that the responsible is a code with no relation what so ever with time. Actually the actions in this code are very simple and deterministic (= happens when the button is clicked). I have two questions: why do you think that this is the best candidate to explain the problem? (Shouldn't you be looking at other parts, like different applications communication to that DB, the DB itself, programs performing regular actions, your hardware, etc.?).

Comment: Is this asp.net? Winforms? WPF? Silverlight?

Comment: And why do you think that we can figure out what is happening here by looking at this code? Should we be executing this code for a couple of months and see if we eventually observe this behaviour? Even in case of being an extremely weird error which is only triggered when executing this code a relevant amount of times during a long enough period, how could we solve it here? Shouldn't you have thought carefully about both issues before posting your question?

Comment: @MattWilko For what the OP is asking, It doesn't matter at all.

Comment: It might do if it was asp.net and this was a postback issue.

Comment: @MattWilko How would it make a difference? Why working fine an undetermined number of times and not working once/twice every x months? How could be such a situation be fixed by just looking at this code and the fact of being web-based or not have any effect on such an analysis?

Comment: This is a windows desktop application

Comment: The aforementioned Matt's comment doesn't make any sense here. Please, unreasonable up-/down-voters focus your batch actions in places like Meta, where you can vote up and down all what you want for no reason. Here you should try to keep it real and stop upvoting/downvoting what isn't right/wrong.

Comment: How you know that code inside `button_Click` eventhandler was executed multiply times?

Comment: I come to know through seeing at the database ! I usually saves almost 1 entry per day !

Comment: Code looks fine. The real question is what calls BTnSave_Click()?